# Ethereum Transaction using API

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, ether, etherscan

I want to send Ethereum(ETH) from one individual to another individual using API. so please can you help me to solve out this one.

Comment: Please provide more information or do your own research. This sounds like something asked many times before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've installed web3.js with **v1.0.0** or higher you should have a look over [here](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction).

For a **lower** web3 version check the [github wiki](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction).

Answer (score 0):

> I will suggest simple API of Blockcypher

[Transaction API Link](https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/ethereum/?javascript#transaction-hash-endpoint)

- Easy
- Cheap
- Private  keys with Us only
- Hense Secure